# Dudas CSS border top

Tags: html, css

Buenas, hay alguna forma de hacer un border TOP con margin?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando hago un focus o un hover, que sala un top barr pero un poco más elevado del elemento del focus/hover.

Comment: podeis ver la imagen que he añadido a la pregunta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si estás buscando hacer un menu con `HTML5`, podrías hacerlo así:

```css
body {
  background-color: #666;
}
nav ul{
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
  padding: 0;
}
nav ul li{
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-right: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 5px solid transparent;
}
nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav ul li:hover {
  border-top: 5px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<nav>
 <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 32px;
}

.wrapper {
  padding-top: 16px;
  border-top: 2px solid transparent;
  width: 150px;
}

.wrapper:hover{
  border-top: 2px solid white;
}

.boton {
  padding: 8px;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class='header'>
  <div class='botones'>
    <div class='wrapper'>
      <div class='boton'>
        Texto
      </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Utiliza un `padding` y un `border-top` transparente que cambie de color durante el `:hover`. De esta forma, cuando pases el cursor no veras un salto hacia abajo al dibujar el borde.

Tal como se ve en tu imagen, necesitaras encerrar cada item en un `div` padre que se use para esto.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta usar un wrapper para tu elemento y sobre este wrapper definir un nuevo estilo que complete tus requerimientos de diseño.

```css
.magic-border {
  
  padding-top: 20px;
  border-top: solid 2px black

}

.my-element {

  border: solid 1px black;

}
```

```html
<div class='magic-border'>
  <div class='my-element'>algo<div>
</div>
```